# Из-за чего при запуске приложения вылетает ошибка?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, install

Есть WPF приложение написанное на .NET 4. Пробовал установить приложение на разные компы: Window 10, Window 7(3 компа) и Windows Vista Ultimate (2 компа). На всех компьютерах установлен нужный .NET 4.

На всех компах приложение открывается нормально - без ошибок, кроме одного с Windows Vista Ultimate.

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом на другом компе с той же Windows Vista Ultimate приложение запускается. 
В чём тогда может быть причина ошибки?

---

В интернете читал, что может быть проблема в драйверах (и вправду на этом компе драйвера не были установлены вручную). Потом драйвера поставили, но проблема так и не ушла.

Comment: Мы не знаем вашей программы, что она делает, какие функции ОС задействует,  о каких драверах идет речь ( видеокарты, принтера, сканера, материнской платы, десятки их, о каких речь то?). На случай неожиданного падения приложения во время работы, чтобы программист мог понять и найти ошибку, было придумано логирование работы приложения. Настройте и задействуйте [Trace](http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/create-a-logger-using-the-trace-listener-in-csharp/) для записи в лог файл вызовов методов, записи значений переменных и сообщений об исключениях.

Comment: Проверьте разрядность винды и точную версию установленного фреймворка. Если xaml парсер вернул ошибку, возможно всетаки версия или разрядность подключенной библиотеки фреймворка отличается от требуемой.